# Neo4j data is not showing in Admin console

Tags: java, neo4j

I have created a small java application that use neo4j. Application is running successfully and when I open the neo4j admin console its not showing the data. Here are the steps that I followed.

MainApp.java

```
GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
        GraphDatabaseService db = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(new File("<location>/lang.db"));
        Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
        Node javaNode = db.createNode(Tutorials.JAVA);
        javaNode.setProperty("TutorialID", "JAVA001");
        javaNode.setProperty("Title", "Learn Java");
        javaNode.setProperty("NoOfChapters", "25");
        javaNode.setProperty("Status", "Completed");

        Node scalaNode = db.createNode(Tutorials.SCALA);
        scalaNode.setProperty("TutorialID", "SCALA001");
        scalaNode.setProperty("Title", "Learn Scala");
        scalaNode.setProperty("NoOfChapters", "20");
        scalaNode.setProperty("Status", "Completed");

        Relationship relationship = javaNode.createRelationshipTo
                (scalaNode, TutorialRelationships.JVM_LANGIAGES);
        relationship.setProperty("Id", "1234");
        relationship.setProperty("OOPS", "YES");
        relationship.setProperty("FP", "YES");

        tx.success();

        System.out.println("Done successfully");
        db.shutdown();
        System.out.println("DB Shut down");

public enum Tutorials implements Label {
        JAVA,SCALA,SQL,NEO4J;
    }

    public enum TutorialRelationships implements RelationshipType{
        JVM_LANGIAGES,NON_JVM_LANGIAGES;
    }
```

When I run this it create files in lang.db folder. (Several files)

Then I start the Neo4j Community Edition runner and set the path to lang.db. It started successfully. 
When I navigate to http://localhost:7474/ first it ask to logged in (neo4j/neo4j) and change the password.

When I looked at the Database Information I can see the property keys but not Relationship Types. Even the DB location is correctly configured.

But when I try running some command `MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 100` it says no rows. Am I doing anything wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured. We need to close the transaction to commit the changes.

```
tx.close();
```